# numpy module is not found although installed but import numpy works

Tags: python, numpy

I want to run the python script which imports numpy module.

When I am trying to run, it gives me error as numpy Module not found

```
C:\BSW_development\bp_plarp\Tools\PicoScope>test_pwm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\BSW_development\bp_plarp\Tools\PicoScope\test_pwm.py", line 24, in <module>
    from lib_pico2000a import ScopeCapture

File "C:\BSW_development\bp_plarp\Tools\PicoScope\lib_pico2000a.py", line 20, in <module>

    import numpy as np                                      # linspace
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

although its being installed

```
C:\BSW_development\bp_plarp\Tools\PicoScope>python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.19.5'
>>> exit()`
```

Comment: Even if you run `python test_pwm.py`?

Comment: Try running `python <your script>`

Comment: That is working now. Thanks alot.

Comment: it can be common problem - you may have two Pythons installed and when you run script directly then it may use other Python which may not have `numpy`.